# angularjs $location and window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, route-provider

The URL for my angular app is something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/project/edit/0#/step1   //create new project if project_id = 0
                                   ^
http://www.domain.com/project/edit/1#/step1  //edit existing project if project_id > 0
                                   ^
http://www.domain.com/project/edit/2#/step1  //edit existing project if project_id > 0
                                   ^
```

When the user saves the project and the project_id is 0, i basically just call a server-side script and it returns the project_id of the newly created project (say, "3"). I then update the URL in address bar with the project_id returned by script as follows:

```
window.history.pushState({}, "URL updated", '/project/edit/'+new_project_id);
```

This would change the URL in the address bar without re-loading the page (so if the user pressed save, the URL in address bar would automatically change to `http://www.domain.com/project/edit/3` which is also the URL to edit project later).

But recently I've added `$routeProvider` to my app (I'm using the hash syntax  `#/step1`, `#/step2`, `#/step3` at the end of URL to manage views).

Now I get this `infidig` error whenever I call `window.history.pushState` and also the `$routeProvider` just redirects / reloads the page to `http://www.domain.com/project/edit/0#/step1` instead of changing the URL of address bar.

I've tried using `$location.path` to update my URL, but that changes the part after the hash sign (`#/step1` part) while I want to change the part before the `#` sign (`/edit/0` to `/edit/4`, etc)

**So my question is how do I change the URL in address bar like `window.history.pushState` using `$location` or `$route`?**

Comment: P.S. I've also tried using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

To start, I would recommend that you checkout [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as it has much improved functionality over angular's built in route provider, such as state management and nested views.

Secondly, you really don't change the URL structure before the hash.  The hash (if using this method) should be built off your root url for angular, so `http://www.domain.com/#/`.  Then in your case you would have `http://www.domain.com/#/project/edit/1`

Using ui-router, you create `states`, which are essentially routes.  For example, you may create one like:

`$stateProvider
   .state('project_edit', {
     url: "/project/edit/:id",
     templateUrl: "project.tpl.html",
     controller: ProjectEditController
   })
})`

In your controller or service after you make your request and receive your project id, you would simply call the `$state` service using `$state.go('project_edit', {id : 1})` and you'll be taken to the `ProjectEditController` controller where `id` will be available.

I'd recommend reading the docs for ui-router and go through some of the angular docs as well.  It sounds like you're trying to co-mingle traditional push state usage and angular usage.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. yes, i've used ui-router and i think it is fantastic, especially the nested views.. i'll try using that now. Anyway, you are right that i can just move the project_id after the hash, that is definitely one way to do it, but for now I want to keep the URLs consistent with the current naming scheme `/edit/project/project_id`.. if nothing works out then maybe I'll redirect the old urls to new one, but would be great to learn how I can change the the project_id before hash (it is possible with window.history.pushState.. just need to figure out the angularJS way of doing it)